# SIOd: ran out of storage in festival

Tags: c++, ubuntu, festival

While running the C++ code for festival,i am using multiple languages like american diaphone,italian etc. but when after playing for one language,i select another language then the terminal shows the error "SIOD:ran out of storage" and does not do anything.
Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/festlang-talk/2007-December/000716.html) (from the festival mailing list, 2007) suggests you may need to *increase the heap* in order to run several voices.

I don't know how they ended up resolving this problem (the conversation thread appears to end after this email), whether it frees the memory or whether it keeps all used voices around... my guess is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you were able to solve your proble,, but running `Festival` with an increased heap size usually works. This can be done like so:

`festival --heap 2100000`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help in my case (tried up to 50M).